# how child component get parent component template in Angular4

Tags: angular

Based on below sample

```
// Parent
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `...
               <app-form-wrapper [someInput]="someInput" [otherInput]="otherInput">
                <input>
                other html ...
               /app-form-wrapper>
             ...
            `
})
export class ParentComponent {}

// Child
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-wrapper',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
export class FormWrapperComponent {}
```

Is it possible for FormWrapper component to get those code/HTML wrapped by itself at parent template?

In this case, I wish my FormWrapper component able to get '< input> other HTML ...'

Please don't suggest pass in as an input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can using `ng-content` and transclusion:

```
// Child
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-wrapper',
  template: '<div><ng-content></ng-content></div>'
})
export class FormWrapperComponent {}
```

Comment: is there a way to get the content in FormWrapperComponent constructor but not from template?